# Ceasar coding returns wrong characters

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, ascii, ordinal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86F4v.png)
the issue I think is within the if statement('s) but I can't find the problem after tweaking for a bit.

```
txt = "xofob qyxxk qsfo iye ez, xofob qyxxk vod iye nygx"

def letterschuiven(cha, vsg):

      for let in cha: 
          let = let.lower()

          if let.isalpha():
               numberlet = ord(let) + vsg
               if numberlet < 97:
                  modlet=  numberlet % 26
                  answer = modlet + 97
               else:
                    answer=numberlet
               realans = chr(answer)
               print(realans, end = "")
          else:
               print(let, end = "")
letterschuiven(txt, -10)
```

should return "never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down",
now returns: "neoek gonna gioe ron np, neoek gonna lem ron dopn"

(here the explanation of the def)
I am trying to decode txt using CHA as the string, and vsg as the amount the characters should be moved (-10 here)

gives neoek gonna gioe ron np, neoek gonna lem ron dopn
should return never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down

I tweaked most values a bit but that just made it all worse

I think the answer is pretty simple, but please try to keep it to a beginner level (school project ;))

Comment: Try to replace `modlet=  numberlet % 26` by `modlet=  (numberlet - 97) % 26`.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Notice also how all the problematic characters are in the second half of the alphabet, n-z. Rather than ask somebody to find the problem for you, you should learn how to debug simple programs yourself. Insert `print` statements to get Python to tell you what it's doing in each step, or learn to use the debugger. (I vastly prefer the former, but some people feel exactly the opposite.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the line

```py
modlet =  numberlet % 26
```

to

```py
modlet =  (numberlet - 97) % 26
```

as the 'a' character has the decimal code 97, so you want to set that as 0 before getting mod 26. This way `numberlet - 97` tells you how steps you have to take after 'z', hence `(numberlet - 97) % 26` tells how many steps you have to take from 'a'.

Btw this way you even don't need the

```py
               if numberlet < 97:
                  modlet =  numberlet % 26
                  answer = modlet + 97
               else:
                    answer  =numberlet
```

part, simply use

```py
answer  =  (ord(let) + vsg- 97) % 26 + 97
```

instead.